# Using Task.Delay instead of Application.DoEvents

Tags: c#

Well i was wondering is using `Task.Delay` is better that using Application.DoEvents ?

sample code:

```
private async void NonBlockingWaitAwhile(int milliseconds)
{
    Stopwatch sWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (sWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds <= milliseconds)
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
    }
}
```

or

```
private void WaitAwhile(int milliseconds)
{
    Stopwatch sWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (sWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds <= milliseconds)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

So which method is better (specially that i'v heard that using Application.DoEvents may cause errors because it releases all the pending events the application may do)

Comment: None of the above.  Use a Timer.  And don't tinker with the Visible property, that doesn't work.  Set the Opacity property to 0 in the designer, change it to 0.99 in the Tick event handler.  Not 1.0

Comment: The answers so far are quite good: (1) fix the actual problem, (2) never busy-wait like this, and (3) DoEvents is not a good way to achieve asynchrony. For a lengthier critique of DoEvents-style programming vs proper asynchrony, see my article on the subject in MSDN Magazine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is better than `DoEvents` because it avoids reentrancy.

However, the best solution is to use neither of them. Delays have only a few valid uses, e.g., throttling retries. The vast majority of the time I've seen a delay, it's wrong (e.g., the coder is using it to avoid a race condition or work around an awkward architecture, when the *correct* approach is to fix the actual problem).

Comment: So what if i want to just wait for while in some place without blocking the main thread.

Comment: But *why* do you want to do this?

Comment: when the application starts the form flickers for 1 sec before it become stable so i thought about setting Visible to false then wait for 2 secs and set visible = true again. So the user did not experience that flicker

Comment: The appropriate approach is to fix the "flicker". E.g., use virtualizing controls.

Comment: So using the wait is not a good choice anyway except for very rare situations

Comment: Correct. You can put in the quick hack of `Task.Delay` and get it to work, or you can choose to put in a more correct solution. :)

Comment: Note also that the `DoEvents` version cranks the CPU to 100% since it is a busy loop. This only exacerbates your problem, since you are now starving the other parts of the program that presumably you are waiting to settle. This is the computer version of the manager who stops by every 5 minutes demanding an updated status report.

Answer (score 3):

Application.DoEvents doesn't really create a delay - it forces the main application UI thread to process all the pending Windows messages in the queue. If there's not much to process, it returns very quickly.